# What this probability distribution is? related to Weibull distribution

Tags: probability, statistics

I have a distribution, that is

$f(y) = \frac{\theta}{y^2} \exp (\frac{-\theta}{y})$ where $y>0$ and $\theta>0$.

It's kind of Weibull distribution. The Weibull distribution $(\eta,\beta)$ is

$f(y|\eta,\beta) = \frac{\eta}{\beta} y^{\eta - 1} e^{-\frac{y^\eta}{\beta}}$

But I cannot get the exact parameters matching my Weibull distribution.

Comment: Looks like a [generalized gamma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_gamma_distribution). In any event, if $Y$ has the distribution given by $f(y|\eta,\beta)$, then $U=Y^\eta\beta^{-1}\sim \operatorname{Exp}(1)$.

Comment: Take $X$ to be exponentially distributed. Work out the distribution of $Y := 1/X$.

Comment: It's an [inverse Gamma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse-gamma_distribution).